# I want to fetch each values from this boxes[searchIndex] in javascript

Tags: javascript

boxes[searchIndex] contains these below coordinates,
 I want to fetch each one separately in javascript, How can i do.

```
 ((10.524913844373852, 76.1971892265924), (10.546497562915903, 76.2081680719109))
```

for example i want like this,

```
lat1=10.524913844373852
lat2=10.546497562915903
lng1=76.1971892265924
lng2=76.2081680719109
```

this is the full code, i want to display all coordinates that i saved in my database along the route from point A to B. It's working fine for when fetching places from google map data, but i want to display only my database coordinates(places).for that i want to fetch each values from boxes[searchIndex] and compare with my database to fetch corresponding coordinates from database.

```
function route() {      

 clearBoxes();
  // Convert the distance to box around the route from miles to km
  distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 0.2;
// document.write(distance);
  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
    destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }

  // Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

      // Box around the overview path of the first route

      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;

      boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      // alert(boxes);
       drawBoxes(); 
      findPlaces(0);
    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });

}

function drawBoxes() {

  boxpolys = new Array(boxes.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: boxes[i],
      fillOpacity: 0,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      map: map
    });
  }
}

function findPlaces(searchIndex) {
  var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
  var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var request = {
    bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
  };
  //var aa=boxes[searchIndex];
  document.write(boxes[searchIndex]);
 if (!!type && (type != "")) {
    if (type.indexOf(',') > 0)
      request.types = type.split(',');
    else
      request.types = [type];
  } 
   if (!!keyword && (keyword != "")) request.keyword = keyword;
  if (!!name && (name != "")) request.name = name;
  service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds[" + searchIndex + "] returns " + results.length + " results<br>"
      for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(result);
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds[" + searchIndex + "] returns 0 results<br>&nbsp;status=" + status + "<br>";
    }
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
      searchIndex++;
      if (searchIndex < boxes.length)
        findPlaces(searchIndex);
    } else { // delay 1 second and try again
      setTimeout("findPlaces(" + searchIndex + ")", 1000);
    }

  });
}

function clearBoxes() {
  if (boxpolys != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxpolys.length; i++) {
      boxpolys[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  boxpolys = null;
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  if (place.icon) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      place.icon, new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
  } else var image = {
    url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  var request = {
    reference: place.reference
  };
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var contentStr = '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5><p>' + place.formatted_address;
        if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>' + place.formatted_phone_number;
        if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a>';
        contentStr += '<br>' + place.types + '</p>';
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });

  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  if (!place.name) place.name = "result " + gmarkers.length;
  var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a><br>";
  document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
}
```

Comment: Help us help you, provide more code, and what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: How is this question related to PHP? Where does that string come from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `let [lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2] = "((10.524913844373852, 76.1971892265924), (10.546497562915903, 76.2081680719109))".match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g)`

Comment: @ IncredibleHat I updated my code

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your response. I done like this boxes[searchIndex].toString().match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g); , it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this RegExp `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/` and execute the [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function

```js
var data = '((10.524913844373852, 76.1971892265924), (10.546497562915903, 76.2081680719109))';

var coordinates = data.match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g);

console.log(coordinates[0]);
console.log(coordinates[1]);
console.log(coordinates[2]);
console.log(coordinates[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when i am giving direct like this                                                                                                          var data = '((10.524913844373852, 76.1971892265924), (10.546497562915903, 76.2081680719109))'; working fine but when i putting like this var data=boxes[searchIndex]; it's showing console error Uncaught TypeError: data.match is not a function

Comment: @StevinGeorge this `boxes[searchIndex]` returns a string?

Comment: document.write(boxes[searchIndex]);  it gives me output 
((10.535705703644878, 76.17523153595539), (10.568081281457953, 76.18072095861464))

Comment: @StevinGeorge try this `boxes[searchIndex].toString().match()`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine, i got like this 10.54110163328039,76.16425269063689,10.595060929635514,76.16974211329625.

Comment: @StevinGeorge Yes, you need to convert to Array.